# Gulp watch task, multiple folders with chained onchange

Tags: gulp, task, watch, browser-sync

Why does this work

```
gulp.task("watch", ["browser-sync"], function() {
  gulp.watch(
    ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss", "src/scss/*.scss"],
    ["sass"],
  );
  gulp.watch("src/*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

But this does not work:

```
gulp.task("watch", ["browser-sync"], function() {
  gulp.watch(
    ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss", "src/scss/*.scss"],
    ["sass"],
    ["src/*.html"]
  ).on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

Hmmm, Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

`Gulp.watch` has this declaration:

```
gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)
```

See [gulp.watch documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb).  You have

```
gulp.watch(
    ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss", "src/scss/*.scss"],
    ["sass"],
    ["src/*.html"]
```

which is equivalent to

```
gulp.watch(glob, task, glob)
```

which just isn't allowed.  You could fix it by doing something like:

```
gulp.task("watch", ["browser-sync"], function() {
  gulp.watch(
    ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss", "src/scss/*.scss"],
    ["sass"]);
  gulp.watch(["src/*.html"]).on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

and then put a reload call at the end of your 'sass' task.

Comment: I see! Thanks very much for your reply, and help 

Comment: You are welcome.  If you find the answer helpful and accurate, you might consider accepting it.